# android: resized images fuzzy on the second page

Tags: android, css, resize, background-image

Toolbar:

```
#main_bar {
    background: url(../images/logo.jpg) 99% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 80%;
}
```

logo.jpg original size 220x266px

the height of the toolbar is 46px

so the background image has height of about 36px

the toolbar is the same on all pages (there are 2 pages in total)

My problem is:
The image looks perfect when app starts. It becomes fuzzy when I pass to the second page. And it remains fuzzy when I return to the first page.

if changed to

```
background-size: auto 36px;
```

the problem remains

Any suggestions?

Thank you,
Irina

Answer (score 0):

public  Bitmap resizeBitMapImage1(String filePath, int targetWidth,int targetHeight)
             {

```
          Bitmap bitMapImage = null;
       Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        double sampleSize = 0;

        Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math
                .abs(options.outWidth - targetWidth);

        if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {

            sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight
                    : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
            sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d,
                    Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
        }


        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[128];
        while (true) {
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize;
                bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    sampleSize = sampleSize * 2;
                } catch (Exception ex1) {

                }
            }
        }

        return bitMapImage;
    }
```